# Using import statement with Cloud functions in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I recently migrated my cloud functions project to typescript, and i'm trying to deploy it in vain.
The versions of my project :

```
"node": "12"
"firebase-admin": "^9.4.1"
"firebase-functions": "^3.13.0"
"typescript": "^4.1.2"
```

My code :

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
...
```

The error :

```
/Users/macbook/oneflash/prod/qrflash/functions/src/index.ts:6
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1172:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1277:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1105:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1145:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:15:15
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:53:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1256:30)
```

My tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "allowJs": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonJS",
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Note : I checked that i have this line : "module": "commonJS" since it is the answer i found about this topic on the internets but i still have this painfull issue.

Comment: I suggest running `firebase init` in a new folder and start a new project from scratch to get its default configuration.  Then copy your old code into that new space.

Comment: @DougStevenson at the end of the day, i created a new folder and started a new project and copied the fresh conf into my current project. After some tweeks, it finaly is back to prod ... Thanks a lot for this suggestion